# Design Management Software

Tags: software-recommendation, project-management

I like keeping a rigurous control over all the design works I do, because that way I can keep a record and track all my work with clients, prices, times, type of designs, etc.

Right now I'm doing this with an Excel made by myself with all the parameters I want to keep a record of. But maintaining an Excel is not efficient at all and consumes a lot of my time.

**Is there a software that can keep a record of my design works?** That automates at some level the task of keeping track of the works I made. And if that software can generate automatic reports, informs and invoices for the works, that would be awesome too.

Don't want a cloud-based or a web-based solution, or a mobile app. I'm looking for a desktop software with a local database (no Internet) that let me keep a relation of my works, like a catalogue or some kind of portfolio, with the ability to make reports and invoices for that works.

Comment: Possible duplicates of this question can be found [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27539/offline-billing-software-for-freelancers) and [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6213/simple-hosted-file-tracking/6240#6240)

Comment: @PieBie thanks for the links, but those are not the softwares I want... Don't want cloud-based or web-based solutions, or a mobile app, I'm looking for a desktop software with local database (not cloud database). Also I don't want time-tracking feature, because I would never use it. What I want is a sort of catalogue or portfolio software, when I can keep a relation of all the work I'm doing, and generate reports and invoices for that works.

Comment: First, did you look at the first link, it specifically asks for _desktop applications_. Second, how can you generate invoices if you're not tracking time? Third, you can easily use a Project management tool without it's time tracking feature. So I still don't see how your needs differ from what is already on offer in the answers to the other questions.

Comment: @PieBie There are a lot of ways to price your work, and I'm not use the time fact for that. So, I'll generate an invoice only with the work I do, not for tasks or time consumed. But most important of that, my key need is to keep a record of the work I've made, like a catalogue or a portfolio, but automated in a software. The first link ask for a software more for manage a lot of things. I don't want a software for a lot of things because I don't have time! I only want to keep records for my works in an automate way. The needs are different!

Comment: @FiroKun You dont have time because you do not track time. You can not do better time management unless you know where you could save time. Tracking time makes you better of regardless of pricing model.

Comment: @joojaa Yes, I know time tracking is important. But I'm my current situation isn't effective for many reasons that don't come to matter now.

Comment: Software is made for general use -- not for individual users. It sounds like you're looking for software that does _exactly_ what _you_ need it to and nothing more, nothing less. I think you're going to need to change your standards a bit here.

Answer (score 2):

If you're comfortable in Excel, you might look at Microsoft Access. It's intended for small database needs like you're describing.

Once you learn Access, you can build your own reports, invoices, and forms to make it easy to enter data. It can also work with images, for example thumbnails of your designs.